# jquery.cookie plugin, gettign an error saying jquery is not defined?

Tags: jquery

I included the `jquery.cookie.js` in my application and I am getting a firefox error saying jquery is not defined?

I have jquery in the project FOR SURE, removing the `jquery.cookie.js` script gets rid of the error.

**What could be the reason for this?**

Comment: Is jquery.cookie.js included before or after jquery itself?

Comment: Try it one a blank HTML file to get it working first, just in case there are complication with the other elements on your app's page.

Comment: crescentfresh, I thought order doesn't matter with javascript??

Comment: crescentfresh, you want to submit an answer?

Comment: @mrblah: looks like *@RedWolves* beat me to it.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have jQuery declared before jQuery.cookie.js

You can't use the jQuery object until it's declared and thus why it does matter the order.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using mulitple versions of jquery in one script you might get that error. solution

[Using different versions of jQuery and jQueryUI together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214551/using-different-versions-of-jquery-and-jqueryui-together)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure jQuery is available wrap your jQuery code in:

```
(function ($) {
     // your Code.
})(jQuery);
```

Additionally you may check for jquery.cookie:

```
(function ($) {
    if (typeof $.cookie != 'undefined'){
        var test = ($.cookie('test') === 'true');
    }
})(jQuery);
```